# Do we really need an old cars tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we really need an [old-cars](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-cars) tag?  I approved the edit to the tag wiki today, didn't even realize this tag existed. Is it useful?

Excerpt

> Old cars cover oldtimers as well as youngtimers, i.e. nearly all cars
>   without electronics, or cars that have been designed and built first
>   multiple decades ago (but maybe still being built somewhere around the
>   globe).

Summary

> Questions which should be tagged "old-cars":
>
> - Anything concerning oldtimers or youngtimers
> - Anything about cars being built for multiple decades without much modification, e.g. including recent Brasilian VW Transporters which
>     are based on the 2nd generation of the VW Transporter, recent
>     Hindustan Ambassadors which are based on Morris Minor from the '50s.
> - Anything concerning cars which are officially registered as Oldtimer, e.g. Germany-registered cars with an "H" suffix or "07"
>     prefix on the number-plate.
> - Anything concerning cars without any electronics.
> - Anything concerning used cars whose prices are already rising again.
>
> Questions which should not be tagged "old-cars":
>
> - Anything concerning cars which have first being built less than 10 to 15 years ago.
>
> Examples:
>
> - VW Golf 1 ('70s + '80s) or VW Golf 2 ('80s + '90s) are surely on-topic
> - VW Golf 5 or VW Golf 6 are off-topic
> - VW Golf 3 ('90s) maybe on-topic nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be about as useful as [new-car](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-car) would be. I'd say get rid of it ... I think I had the same question about it before when looking at it. It is *very* subjective. My idea of an "old car" is quite different from yours.